# JDBC mysql sistema operacional MacOS

Tags: java

olá

Não existe mais o conector JDBC Mysql para MacOS ?

pesquisei no site do MySql e nao encontrei.

obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Como o connector do MySQL é uma lib Java, você pode utilizar em todas as plataformas utilizando a opção `Platform Independent` no sistema operacional da [página de download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Ou baixar de algum repositório utilizando uma ferramenta de gerenciamento de dependências como o Maven, você pode encontrar no [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) por exemplo.